# how to use guice injector in order to bind mapping dynamically

Tags: java, guice

Can you give an example how can i use guice in a way of binding the interface to 
concrete types using strings that describes the class name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this interface and class

```
interface MyClass {}
class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {}
```

Then bind it as

```
String className = "my.package.MyClassImpl";
bind(MyClass.class).to(Class.forName(className));
```

Of course you can check for exceptions in the case of wrong string.